# Uniform number format for labels and text

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have a Vega-Lite visualization that works on data sets whose field values range from 0 to millions.
I am trying to have uniform SI format across axis, legend, mark and tooltips such that the unit (k, M etc.) changes according to the value, keeping the precision same. (2 decimal places for the below example)

[Sample in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNhgUQgCdum1vDxXIABQCMakaajAjcrEpeOACsAJwALHR+UclxAGx+AOwx0qr2kM7IVErmVgBMUZlRdNIxMX4xpQAcAAwZcfYAvur2EI6QLm4ekVA+pYFaIfBhEVa1DVVxcRXNS6kxuUYFRSU4jXExqc1+dI0ZZ9JHUY0xhl12hn0D7p7ePtLjkMGh4cNRpXSlUrZQ61UobPJbZDFZBWDJ+Rp0dJxGoZVp+aQ9MB3TGPVzPYa+OIfL5TH5WPx+ZrZY7NRpXKJxOmNDb5QpQnZgJIxM5-Og8xqZRnJCAde4AXQ02NwyEY1HwVguzW6UAA7oxNCwFc0lRpIOhWHhuLBGAAvGH6SBTCLoRhKSw4froTTBJTUQKQPAAT0I5qgADNmJApZAoVMXW79PdIAAPKwGHqQAPIMSabxPIbur0+7zcZwu0xqe5GdDRkJxz7cDC2qx+0ywZC5D2MeAAa3tYFrYnrjbwzDEvuKYjEjbE6HYyYAgq7+1ZmqLOsqjJ640X-Yxk6mHZDoZnvb7IABHVjoCLMHSMKiFzF60vt+PXzSVm0qHCd7tQXut9tvhsfvsD1gh0XBM-VzDACWgVQAUsVd51uSVlUgUdPWQZwrFsex70MSAMGcFtyyzfd2HQNCpTyUM3FtCMHFXIwpjEXMV0xPIkxTbxtxKHs928I8T17XRe0vYDrwQUxfWAfIT2oX1rEgABiAAxABRABhAARNSYndRSWkWAIxTI5ikJoKFNxo5iE34mccEHYcoGoZwnXXCIABkoWoTUcCSJU-1bFTpmGPxhKM0DnHA7xIOgyBaPgiy4M6e5DKwoxcPwi1CO8PBkGjLxG00ZccBEKJDKMCjwyYoyspy8tWLM1lthhLjswdXjTwEi9Gv9MCdAiqDSkseLYqGiUOiAA)

[image: SI format]

On Y axis, with `"format": "$,.2s"`, the labels always follow the precision of 2 decimal places and are constrained to the highest unit applicable for the applied data set. Legend labels work similarly, but the value 718.6 is rendered as 0.00M.

On the `text` channel, `format` has a different output. The units change according to the value, but there is no control over precision. Values are trimmed without even specifying `~`.

```json
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "revenue", "type": "quantitative", "format": "$,.2s"}
      }
    }
```

Formatting the values using calculate also gives same output.

```json
    {
      "calculate": "format(datum['revenue'],'$,.7s')",
      "as": "revenue_text"
    }
```

Is there any configuration by which the units of `axis` & `legend` labels would vary as the values increase?
For `text`, how to ensure a fixed precision?

Something on the lines of 100.00 (without any unit symbol), then 100.00k then 1.00M and so on, maintaining the specified precision.

```
                  +------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
                  |            |                      Present Output                       |
    +-------------+  Expected  +-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    |    value    |   Output   | (format: '$,.2s') | (format: '$,.3s') | (format: '$,.7s') |
    +-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    | 25175.39919 | $25.18k    | $25k              | $25.2k            | $25.17540k        |
    | 849601.8777 | $849.60k   | $850k             | $850k             | $849.6019k        |
    | 718.6143971 | $719.00    | $720              | $719              | $718.6144         |
    | 1597752.776 | $1.60M     | $1.60M            | $1.60M            | $1.597753M        |
    +-------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

### Identifying the culprit

> “Depending on the type, the precision either indicates the number of digits that follow the decimal point (types f and %), or the number of significant digits (types ​, e, g, r, s and p).”
>   (refer to [d3 format help](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md))

So once you choose SI, you’re stuck with significant digits.

### Limitation of scope

For the legend and axis, I do not have any solution. I’m afraid you may be touching vega-lite’s limits here for now. Furthermore, given the huge domain and your precision requirements (high precision in case of low numbers), a bar chart may no longer be appropriate. If you switched to e.g. a dot plot, you could use a log scale with the original domain values and thus expand/compress the axis values such that you’d have high precision for each label.

### Suggestion for the rest

For the text mark, an alternative will be to write your own format preprocessor. For example in vega-lite, you can use a series of `calculate` transforms to create a new variable in string format. Each calculate expression will test for a different type of number (thousands, millions, etc) and apply the necessary formatting. In your use case there will be 3 such transforms:

- if(thousands, convert to thousands with fixed format, ‘’)
- if(millions, convert to millions with fixed format, return the new variable)
- if(neither thousands nor millions, just convert to fixed format, return the new variable)

In all cases, `as` will contain the same new variable name.

You can recycle the string variable `revenue_text` in your post to test each time for the presence or absence of an SI letter, e.g. the first expression:

```js
if(lastindexof(datum.revenue_text, ‘k’) > 0, format(datum.revenue / 1000, '$,.2s') + 'k', ‘’)
```

The first transform will have ‘’ as an else clause, while any other case must contain the new variable itself. Instead of `lastindexof()`, you can also use `test(`) for regex. Obviously, you can do all this in a single transform - it is probably a matter of taste whichever variety you would consider more readable and maintainable.

P.S. I have no computer to test the said expression right now.